# Oracle query to fetch top 3 salaries of each department

Tags: oracle, subquery

I want a SQL query to fetch top 3 salaries of each department

```
Table :- sample

Name   Salary   Dept
AA      1000    Hr
BB      7520    Store
CC     12500    Hr
DD      9850    Store
EE     10250    Finance
FF     12560    Hr
GG     13500    Store
HH     15680    Store
KK     12853    Hr
MM     17582    Finance
NN     16852    Finance
```

I used the below query but it is not fetching proper result

```
SELECT dept, fname,lname,sal from sample where rownum<4 group by(fname,lname,sal,desg) order by sal desc
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is the analytic function [`row_number`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions156.htm#SQLRF06100)

```
select * 
from (select a.*, row_number() over (PARTITION by dept order by salary desc) as num 
        from sample a
)
where num < 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `group by` and then `where rownum < 4`

```
SELECT dept,fname,lname,sal 
FROM sample 
GROUP BY(fname,lname,sal,desg)
WHERE ROWNUM < 4
ORDER BY sal DESC
;
```

Also check `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` columns as the table only showing NAME and not `fname` and `lname`.

Comment: Hi,the above query still not fetching the desired result

Comment: hv used name,but it is not fetching the desired esult

Comment: Try Pham X solution below.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM(SELECT Name  ,Dept ,Salary  , 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Dept ORDER BY Salary  DESC)AS D_RANK 
FROM sample ) 
WHERE D_RANK <=3;
```

Comment: you can just use the [edit] link instead of deleting and adding an answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM sample a
WHERE
   3 >= ( SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT salary)
          FROM sample b
          WHERE a.salary <= b.salary
            AND a.dept = b.dept
        )
```

Comment: Hello Sidharud, Welcome to StackOverflow for your first answer. I have formatted your answer as code so it is more readable. When my change is visible to you, can you add some explanations to your answer ? Thanks